# LNK304P unexpected output voltage

Tags: power-supply, power, low-power

I trying to understand what problem with next scheme. 
[image]

I have a power supply which should provide +12V but in my case it's only about 5v in output (checked on 1-2-7-8 and Gnd pins). I have tried to change LNK304P to new one but without result. So seems that problem in harness. I assume that problem with PC101 but Now I prefer to be sure before replacing component. Please help to understand could it be problem?

Comment: Where did you find this schematic? And could you link the schematic in its entirety?

Comment: Here is the [LNK304 datasheet](http://www.es.co.th/Schemetic/PDF/LNK304-306.PDF)...

Answer (score 1):

This is, in my opinion, a bizarre buck regulator. It's also rather unsafe because it's a non-isolated mains voltage regulator.

If you want to be sure that PC101 is your issue, I would measure PC101 pins 3 and 4 to check if it's shorted. If it is, then you know that's the issue (or at least the main issue). The other thing to check would be to setup a 10mA current between pins 1 and 2 and measure the resistance on pins 3 and 4. If the resistance drops when you power the opto-coupler, then you know it's still working.

If that turns out to be fine, I would check all of the diodes to make sure they're operating as expected. Use a diode checker on them. They should show an open circuit in one direction and virtually short for the other direction. For the zener's you'll also want to test them for their reverse voltage level. To test that, you need to put a voltage supply with a current limiting resistor on them and voltage probe the diode contacts. You should see approximately the reverse breakdown voltage.